# HTML5 Audio Tag Changing Src when finished. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, element

I have created a audio element with a ul. In the ul is list items which are linked to different songs. I have gotten the song to change when the item is clicked and it all works however i would like the song to also change when the current playing song finishes. Below is my html and js.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mp3_player">
    <div id="audio_box">
        <audio id="audioPlayer" preload="auto" src="" controls="controls"></audio>
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="songSelector">
    <a href="song1.mp3"><li>song1</li></a>
    <a href="song2.mp3"><li>song2</li></a>
    <a href="song3.mp3"><li>song3</li></a>
    <a href="song4.mp3"><li>song4</li></a>
</ul>
```

The source doesn't have a value becasuse it is added in another part of my script.

**JS:**

```
$(audio).bind('ended', function() {
    var testing = $('#songSelector').next().attr('href');
    alert(testing);
})
```

The alert returns undefined when the song finished when it should return the link on the next li element. I just cant figure out what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: you know your HTML is invalid, right? you cannot wrap `LI` inside `A`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan  Yes i do know it was just to quickly make my life a bit easier however i am changing it so that there is no A tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, `$('#songSelector').next()` is going to whatever is after `#songSelector` in the dom. You probably need to keep track of which one is "current" in another variable.

```
var currentSong = $('#songSelector').find('a:first');
$(audio).bind('ended', function() {
    var next = currentSong.next();
    if ( next.length ) {
        currentSong = next;
    } else {
        /* uncomment this if you want it to loop back to the beginning */ 
        // currentSong = $('#songSelector').find('a:first');
    }
    var testing = currentSong.attr('href');
    alert(testing);
});
```

Then you just need to update `currentSong` in your `click` handler as well.

Comment: Sorry about all the questions but i am new to js :). Is there a way that i could add a class "active" to the currentSong element so the user knows what the song has changed to. I got this working when clicking and changing song but i cant get it working when it automatically changes. Sorry again :)

Comment: It's not problem. Because of jQuery's chaining, you can do this:

`var testing = currentSong.addClass('active').attr('href');`

and at the beginning part

`var next = currentSong.removeClass('active').next();`

Hopefully that will at least get you on the right track.

Comment: I have just noticed that it worked between the first and second song however it then just repeats the first song in the list. The above answer also doesn't seem to work. I have to rewrite the program into jquery because currently it is jquery and raw js so :( thanks for your help and i will see how i do :)